# EnetityManager assigning multiple values to a key

Tags: hibernate, entitymanager

```
em.createQuery("""
                select s.description, avg(c.taktTime)
                from CountEntity c, SkillEntity s, FwmsUserEntity u, SkillTypeEntity t
                where c.fwmsUser = u.id
                   *AND s.description in (:skillsList)*
                   AND c.skill = s.id
                   AND t.id=6 AND t.id=s.skillType
                   GROUP BY s.description """).setParameter("skillsList", skillsListStr)
```

.getResultList()

I am getting a `String skills = ('Shelf Count', 'Notion Count', 'Tube Count', '2nd Count')`. How do I assign this variable 'skills' to s.description in below query? Please see that those values are now hardcoded and I would like to pass them dynamically.

```
em.createQuery("""
                select s.description, avg(c.taktTime)
                from CountEntity c, SkillEntity s, FwmsUserEntity u, SkillTypeEntity t
                where c.fwmsUser = u.id
                   *AND s.description in ('Shelf Count', 'Notion Count', 'Tube Count', '2nd Count')*
                   AND c.skill = s.id
                   AND t.id=6 AND t.id=s.skillType
                   GROUP BY s.description """).getResultList()
```

Comment: I now know how to do it.

Comment: By adding actual values I am getting the result back, but when I put the key parameters in a string variable (as shown in the original post), the query is not returning any values back (list size is 0) and there were no SQL errors? how do you guys handle this?

Comment: you could concat the strings `... in` + skills + `AND..`